# In word, the columns isn't continuous when meeting the page break and how?

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is my question: I use three columns in the middle of my document to put three tables side by side in a sperate section. However, these columns aren't continuous when they meet the new page. What I want is that these three tables are just at their own columns, even when there exists a new page break.(I have posted it on the StackOverflow and someone advises me to post here.)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with columns as you tried.

Closest workaround could be to insert a table with three columns and one rows, set it to have even column widths, then insert your tables into the cells of this new table. (Of course you can remove borders of the big table, so finally it would look like as you expect.)